# What's the name of a function of the form $y(x;p) = p f(x) + (1-p) g(x)$?

Tags: notation

Is there a name for a function of the form $y(x;p) = p f(x) + (1-p) g(x)$, where $p$ is some scalar between 0 and 1, and $f$ and $g$ are functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convex combination of $f$ and $g$. For more information see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination.

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then so is $y$ and the derivative with respect to $x$ is given by $pf'(x)+(1-p)g'(x)$, so the derivative of a convex combination is the convex combination of the individual derivatives.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is "convex" an overloaded term here? As in, when I think of functions being convex, it seems to have a special meaning. Although my impression of convexity here might be a special case of something more general then?

Comment: Also: is there a known formula for the derivative of a convex combination?

Comment: I added some detail :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll accept when the time limit expires. By the way, do you know anything about the derivative of the log of a convex combination? In reality I have $\log(y(x;p))$.

Comment: Actually, wolframalpha was able to answer that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are very welcome.